# google translate api trouble

Tags: curl, google-translate

i'm trying to put the google translate api to work in my webapp. i'm using some ajax to get the translation loaded into a div, but when i do this on my laptop in eclipse i get an error about 50% of the time saying that there is no index 'data' from the json response. I think this is because the api hasnt responded yet so i'm hoping I an put a loop in here to let the code wait, but i'm not sure where. here's the php page that generates the xml response

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$cc_nlc = 'good';
if(isset($_POST['cc_nlc'])){
    $cc_nlc = $_POST['cc_nlc'];
    if(empty($cc_nlc)){
        $cc_nlc = 'not very good';
    }
}
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
echo '<response>';
echo '<translation>';

$apikey = 'my key';

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apikey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($cc_nlc) . '&source=en&target=ar';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($handle);
//print_r($responseDecoded);
$translation = $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];

echo $translation;

echo '</translation>';
echo '</response>';
?>
```